# Notifying a consumer thread before or after releasing the lock on the mutex?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

Below is listing 4.5 from the book *C++ concurrency in action* that defines a thread-safe queue using condition variables.

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <queue>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
class threadsafe_queue
{
private:
    mutable std::mutex mut;
    std::queue<T> data_queue;
    std::condition_variable data_cond;
public:
    threadsafe_queue()
    {}
    threadsafe_queue(threadsafe_queue const& other)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(other.mut);
        data_queue=other.data_queue;
    }

    void push(T new_value)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        data_queue.push(new_value);
        data_cond.notify_one();
    }

    void wait_and_pop(T& value)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        data_cond.wait(lk,[this]{return !data_queue.empty();});
        value=data_queue.front();
        data_queue.pop();
    }

std::shared_ptr<T> wait_and_pop()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
    data_cond.wait(lk,[this]{return !data_queue.empty();});
    std::shared_ptr<T> res(std::make_shared<T>(data_queue.front()));
    data_queue.pop();
    return res;
}

bool try_pop(T& value)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
    if(data_queue.empty)
        return false;
    value=data_queue.front();
    data_queue.pop();
}

std::shared_ptr<T> try_pop()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
    if(data_queue.empty())
        return std::shared_ptr<T>();
    std::shared_ptr<T> res(std::make_shared<T>(data_queue.front()));
    data_queue.pop();
    return res;
}

bool empty() const
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
    return data_queue.empty();
}
};

int main()
{}
```

In the push function, another thread is being notified while the mutex is still locked. Isn't it better to notify popper threads right after the mutex is released. For example, like this:

```
void push(T new_value)
{
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut)
        data_queue.push(new_value);
    }
    data_cond.notify_one();
}
```

I am aware that they are functionally do the same thing. I'm thinking in the original case, the consumer thread will receive a false notification that eventually makes it to try locking the mutex more than once. However, in the second case, we avoid waking up the consumer thread early, and therefore, tries to lock the mutex can be successful in the very first time.

Comment: "Better" here is a bit ambiguous. With spurious wake-up to check the condition, and the fact that the thread will attempt to grab the lock anyway, I think they're more or less the same.

Comment: By "better" I meant performance-wise. I'm thinking the second case would  be faster and also will result in lower energy consumption.

Comment: Have a little faith in the OS scheduler. :)

Answer (score 0):

That does not matter, the end result is going to be the same. If you first notify and than unlock the mutex, the listening thread will be notified, but will be still locked on the mutex, once the mutex is unlocked, thread will proceed.

If you first unlock the mutex, the thread will not know that condition is ready until it is notified and will be waiting on condition variable (barred spurious wake ups).

In the end, the listening thread will proceed only once both conditions are met - mutex is unlocked, variable is notified.

Comment: Thanks. I elaborated the question a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Preceding answers are wrong, your initial assertion is correct. It is better to first unlock, then notify.
While some implementations can avoid the hurry up and wait problem, notably some pthreads implementations, most do not.

This has significant real performance impacts if you are looking at latency, rather than throughput.